# Тело post запроса

Tags: php, post, curl

Есть сайт, который отправляет пост запрос, где в теле запроса лишь текст (Сообщение, которое вводит пользователь). Например: "text текст". Я увидел это через Fiddler, т.е. названия самого параметра нет, просто текст.

Когда я пробую отправить post запрос этому сайту через свой, то сообщение отправляется, но на другом сайте у него некорректный вид. Пример: "=text+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82".

Как сформировать запрос, чтобы сообщения на выходе было в нормальном виде?

Вот пример кода:

```
$curlz = curl_init();
$agent = '...';
curl_setopt_array($curlz, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array(
        ''=>'text текст',
    ))
));

curl_setopt($curlz, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
$response = curl_exec($curlz);
curl_close($curlz);

echo "Ответ: ".$response;
```

Comment: Смотрите в сторону кодировки в которой работает сайт-цель и кодировки отправляемых вами данных.

Comment: С кодировкой еще ладно, хоть я пробовал ставить все так, как и в оригинальном запросе, ничего не менялось. 
Меня больше интересует, как избавить от "=","+" и т.д., всех этих соединительных символов, например. Получается, я передаю название параметра и текст в нем, но в этом нет необходимости.

Comment: Вы используете функцию http://php.net/manual/ru/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'text текст'`

Comment: @Etki, ох, понятно теперь, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы передать произвольные данные в теле POST запроса нужно всего лишь задать правильное значение параметру `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. Дополнительно, можно выставить HTTP заголовок `Content-Type` с правильным значением.

Если вы используете в качестве значения `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` массив, например такой

```
array(
    'a' => 'test_a',
    'b' => 'test_b'
)
```

то CURL отправит запрос с `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` а массив будет преобразован в строку вида `a=test_a&b=test_b`.

Для того, чтобы задать тело запроса *полностью*, нужно задать параметру `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` строковое значение, содержащее данные, которые нужно отправить:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'data_to_send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: text/plain'));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```